# Algorithm in Python - group the people who have the same hobbies

Tags: python, algorithm

I've got a dataset which contains people and their hobbies. Each person is a tuple where the first element is the name and the second element is a list of hobbies of the person. What I want to do is to group the people based on their hobbies. If they got exactly the same hobbies, then they are in the same group.

```
hobbies_list= [
                ("Amy", ["painting", "swimming", "listening to music"]),
                ("Bob", ["swimming", "football","basketball","water polo"]),
                ("Cindy", ["swimming", "listening to music", "painting"]),
                ("David", ["table tennis", "basketball", "volleyball"]),
                ("Edward", ["tennis", "basketball", "volleyball", "water polo"]),
                ("Frank", ["table tennis", "volleyball", "basketball"]),
                ("George", ["volleyball", "basketball", "table tennis"])
        ]
```

So for the above list, the expected result would be:

```
-------------------------------
|Group 1 | Amy, Cindy          |
--------------------------------
|Group 2 | Bob                 |
--------------------------------
|Group 3 | David, Frank, George |
---------------------------------
|Group 4 | Edward               |
---------------------------------
```

How to achieve this in O(MN) without using set and dictionary? Note: N is the length of the hobbies_list and M is the maximum total number of characters of someone's hobby. For example, M is 35 in this case as `["tennis", "basketball", "volleyball", "water polo"]` the longest and got 35 characters.
My idea so far is that the time complexity suggests that we shouldn't use a loop inside a loop for comparing the hobbies of each person, but I don't know how to do the comparisons with only one loop.

Comment: Why not use sets and dictionaries? That would be the most natural thing to do.

Comment: By the way I think M means the number of hobbies in a list, not the total length of the names of the hobbies. So in this case M = 4, not 35.

Comment: @mkrieger1 Hmm, if you think that 4 vs 35 matters, that suggests that you think hobby names could be arbitrarily long. In which case M does need to be the 35, otherwise you can't have O(NM) because I could always include two sufficiently long names that you can't compare fast enough.

Comment: It's an interview question that my friend got a while back. Yes, agree that sets and dictionaries would make life a lot easier, but he was explicitly asked to now use sets and dictionaries. Lol .... Maybe some self-designed string comparisons are expected.

Comment: it seems combinatorics problem... try using for ex ```combinations()``` from ```itertools``` together with ```set``` to find intersections

Comment: I am positive that the M is 35 in this case. M is the maximum total number of characters among all the hobbies.

Answer (score 1):

Following is possibly O(MN*log(M)

- Timing based upon sort step which has O(M*log(M)) comparisons
  with each comparison O(N), thus O(MN*log(M)) overall
- However, faster than native Python solutions since it uses Python library functions sort and groupby
- Basic Python solutions using only for loops are much slower by comparison

**Code**

```
from itertools import groupby

def compare(lst):
    '''
        Key function for matching list of hobbies for a person
        
        It maps list to sorted string without white space
        We remove whitespace since we don't want to distinguish volleyball from volley ball
    ''' 
    return ''.join(sorted(v.replace(" ", "") for v in lst))

# Sort to place people with similar hobbies adjacent
sorted_hobbies = sorted(hobbies_list, key = lambda kv: compare(kv[1]))           # For groupby, matching items need to be adjacent

# Group people with simlar hobbies
groups = groupby(sorted_hobbies, lambda kv: compare(kv[1]))                      

# Show results
for i, (k, v) in enumerate(groups, start = 1):
    print(f'Group {i}: {[t[0] for t in v]}')
```

**Output**

```
Group 1: ['Bob']
Group 2: ['David', 'Frank', 'George']
Group 3: ['Edward']
Group 4: ['Amy', 'Cindy']
```

Comment: I assume `groupby` is from `itertools`?

Comment: @JanChristophTerasa--yes, updated my answer to reflect that.

Comment: What is the purpose of `''.join(...)` in the `compare` function? You can compare directly, eg `groupby(sorted(hobbies_list, key=lambda p:sorted(p[1])), key=lambda p:sorted(p[1]))` returns the correct result.

Comment: @Stef--in the original question (seems to have changed) the poster spelled some of the hobbies differently.  For instance he/she had both "volleyball" and "volley ball" .  The more complex `''.join(sorted(v.replace(" ", "") for v in lst))` allowed such variations.

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own "dict" by storing tuples as hashes and values

```
hashes = []
names = []
for name, hobbies in hobbies_list:
    hashv = tuple(sorted(hobbies))
    if hashv not in hashes:
        hashes.append(hashv)
    names.append((hashv, name))

for i, h in enumerate(hashes):
    print(f'Group {i+1}: ', [name for hashv, name in names if hashv == h])
```

Result:

```
Group 1:  ['Amy', 'Cindy']
Group 2:  ['Bob']
Group 3:  ['David', 'Frank', 'George']
Group 4:  ['Edward']
```

With a bit of extra work you can create your own little class for this.

Comment: Can you explain how this is O(NM)?

Answer (score 0):

Almost certainly not what you want but you *could* do it like this. Note: I fixed a typo in your data to ensure that you get the output as stated in your question.

```
hobbies_list = [
    ("Amy", ["painting", "swimming", "listening to music"]),
    ("Bob", ["swimming", "football", "basketball", "water polo"]),
    ("Cindy", ["swimming", "listening to music", "painting"]),
    ("David", ["table tennis", "basketball", "volleyball"]),
    ("Edward", ["tennis", "basketball",
                "volley ball", "water polo"]),
    ("Frank", ["table tennis", "volleyball", "basketball"]),
    ("George", ["volleyball", "basketball", "table tennis"])
]

normalisedList = [(n, sorted(p)) for n, p in hobbies_list]

G = 1

while len(normalisedList) > 0:
    names = [normalisedList[0][0]]
    pi = [0]
    for i in range(1, len(normalisedList)):
        if normalisedList[i][1] == normalisedList[0][1]:
            names.append(normalisedList[i][0])
            pi.append(i)
    for i in pi[::-1]:
        normalisedList.pop(i)
    print(f'Group {G} ', end='')
    for i, n in enumerate(names):
        if i > 0:
            print(', ', end='')
        print(n, end='')
    print()
    G += 1
```

The result of this will be:-

Group 1 Amy, Cindy
Group 2 Bob
Group 3 David, Frank, George
Group 4 Edward

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that uses sets to avoid sorting each hobby list:

```
hobby_set_list = []
groups = []

for item in hobbies_list:
    if set(item[1]) not in hobby_set_list:
        hobby_set_list.append(set(item[1]))
        groups.append([item[0]])
    else:
        groups[hobby_set_list.index(set(item[1]))].append(item[0])
        
print(groups)
#[['Amy', 'Cindy'], ['Bob'], ['David', 'Frank', 'George'], ['Edward']]
```